# How to set /MP in MSBuild with a specified cpu count

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

I'm trying to speed up building of a C++ project consisting of multiple large files. Adding `<MultiProcessorCompilation>true</MultiProcessorCompilation>` to *.vcxproj file works and speed improvement is nice but since it uses all available cpus, it can make my machine unresponsive for a while.

Is there any way of passing an argument  to /MP option of the compiler through a *.vcxproj project file (since I want to get the benefit when building using Visual Studio)?

Refactoring / splitting the project is not an option at this time unfortunately.

Comment: You are asking for so many different things, it's hard to tell, what you really need to know.

Comment: There is only one question there :) Edited it to be more clear what I'm asking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the max number of the processes that will be used during compilation on projects's configuration properties, C/C++ - Command Line, Additional Options:

/MP[processMax]

where processMax is the required number.

As Microsoft states

> If you omit the processMax argument, the compiler retrieves the number
>   of effective processors on your computer from the operating system,
>   and creates a process for each processor

So, you should experiment with the processMax value, to decide which is best suited for your system in order to be responsive.

When you specify /MP [processMax] e.g. /MP4 in project's configuration properties ( C/C++ - Command Line, Additional Options) this is actually saved in vcxproj file as: `<AdditionalOptions>/MP4</AdditionalOptions>` in `<ClCompile>` element.

Comment: I know that. What I'm asking is how can I pass an argument to /MP option using ms project file.

Comment: On the command line you can use the /maxcoucount switch:msbuild [project] /maxcpucount:[processMax]

Comment: Do you know of any way of specifying that in a .vcxproj file?

Comment: When you specify /MP [processMax] e.g. /MP4 in project's configuration properties ( C/C++ - Command Line, Additional Options) this is actually saved in vcxproj file as: <AdditionalOptions>/MP4</AdditionalOptions> in <ClCompile> element

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Moved that to the answer. Thanks.